# Plan for proving that, for a fixed negative integer $z$, $f(x) = x^z$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I want to prove that, for a fixed negative integer $z$, $f(x) = x^z$  is continuous on $(0, \infty)$.

My plan is to use two known facts: (i) that polynomials are continuous everywhere they are defined and (ii) that the composition of continuous functions, when well-defined, is itself continuous.

Specifically, I have that $p(x) = x^{|z|}$ is a continuous polynomial on the positive reals. If I prove that the function $g(x) = x^{-1} = 1/x$ is continuous on Im($p$), then I'll have that $f(x) = g(p(x))$ is continuous on the positive reals.

Are there any issues in this strategy?

Comment: No, that is probably the most logical way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to prove continuity is to argue that the pre-image of any open interval is open. Since the pre-image of an interval $(a,b)$ is  $(a^{1/z},b^{1/z})$, because the function is monotonic, it's over.

But if you want to use a composition, then apply the definition.

For any $x_0>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |1/x - 1/x_0|=|\frac{x-x_0}{x_0x}|<\varepsilon$$

To show that it is sufficient to pick $\delta<x_0$ such that $$\frac{\delta}{x_0(x_0-\delta)}=\varepsilon $$
If it is bigger that $x_0$, just pick $x_0$.

Cheers.

Comment: OK, could you elaborate on how you would get $\delta$ by itself in the last equation? That is, how would you explicitly choose some value for it?